# Create a WIndows Shortcut with relative path

Tags: windows, cmd, set, shortcut

I am using a mapped drive (connected to a cloud service) on my computer and other people in my firm are using this as well, each of us using different letter for the drive.

I am trying to build a shortcut between two folders on this drive, defined as follows:

```
mappeddriveletter:\\folder1\folder11\name
mappeddriveletter:\\folder2\folder22\name
```

I would like to create a shortcut inside of the first "name" that would take users to the second "name" folder with a different path. The two "name" are the same, the two paths are different.
Therefore the shortcut needs to dynamically do two things : obtain the mappeddriveletter, obtain the "name". And from there get the user to the right place. Folder2\folder2 is known.

I have already created a shortcut and modified the target to obtain the mappeddriveletter and take the user up to mappeddriveletter:\folder2\folder22 :

```
%windir%\system32\cmd.exe /c "%CD:~0,3%\folder2\folder22\"
```

from there I need to obtain the "name" to get inside of the last folder.
I found some code to achieve that (there are some variations but it is more or less that I think) :

```
for %%* in (.) do @echo %%~n*
```

But from now, could you help me figuring out a way to set a variable to this name and then use it in my dynamic path ?
Thanks for your help !

Comment: Mapped drive letters are for compatibility with 16 bit programs (Dos / Windows 3.1). Use UNC - `\\servername\sharename\folder\file.ext`.